# How to Manually create a windows service for Apache 2.2

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, service

I accidentally removed my Apache windows service trying to install another Apache web server. Does anyone know how I can create another Apache windows service from cmd? I tried "sc create ..." but I am missing a script on the end like -k start? Not sure what I need for the end of it...

I am running Apache 2.2

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can put the arguments for the service on the "binPath" argument on your "sc" command, escaping any quotes with slashes. For example, if you wanted to run: "C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe" -service

```
sc create service_name binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe\" -service"
```

Look at the resulting service entry in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\service_name and see if the ImagePath value looks like you want it to.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  it gave me an error saying it could not be started in time.  Error code 1?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache2.2 service can be re-created with the `bin\httpd.exe -k install` command. Then started with the `bin\httpd.exe -k start` command.